# My JavaScript won't work in Jade

Tags: jquery, node.js, pug

I'm working on a website using Node.js. On the front-end I'm using Jade. I have a function that I have used numerous times on other projects that I am certain works correctly.

```
$(function(){
var num = 450; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('#rightnav').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#rightnav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
});
```

Basically the code makes a certain area of the website (the navigation in this case) fixed after you scroll the mouse 450px. I have the script in an external file that I have included in the page I'm working on. I also have jQuery included. I get no errors in the console. However, I've attempted to use console.log to see if it was firing and nothing showed up in my console so I am assuming there is just something I am missing or don't understand about Jade. All my css is included as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, realized that I had to attached the .js file to an additional jade file where my css is.